# token based login in salesforce

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

In custom object i have credential of another org contain username and password , login button as quick action too , i have issue that username and password is visible in url

so its not good so i tried to go through the token based login salesforce ?
as access_token which is generated by client id and client security ,created a connected app for postman to access

used this and get access code to use  in postman ,
tried to login salesforce using access token  which i get by send  oauth2 get request in postman and got instance url and signature and access token by using access token i tried like this

```
http://[instance].salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[access token]
```

open new tab and try to login by the above link.
it  redirect to login page of salesforce and ask again username and pass  for it

Comment: You can use oAuth authentication to login

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the connected App with scope as web / full added so that it gets redirected with the access_token you are using